# Regex pattern - matching capital letters with combination of numbers and a hyphen

Tags: regex

I need help using regular expression. I have some strings with these possibility use cases. The string will always start with a capital letters followed by 3 numbers then with a hyphen, followed by numbers:

```
A012-123
B001-012
C023-456
```

I've tried: `[A-Z0-9]-[0-9]` and i can't get a match. Can someone show me how to construct this correctly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
[A-Z][0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}
```

The `{3}` means that, match only three times. This will match any string which starts with a capital letter, followed by 3 digits, a hypen and 3 digits.

But if the number of digits after `-` can be anything, then you can use

```
[A-Z][0-9]{3}-[0-9]+
```

This match any string which starts with a capital letter, followed by 3 digits, a hypen and *one or more digits.*

**Note:** Instead of writing `[0-9]`, you can use `\d`. They both are one and the same. So your first regex will become

```
[A-Z]\d{3}-\d{3}
```

Comment: You don't need to escape the `-` outside of a character range, and you can use `\d` instead of `[0-9]`, but that's just personal preference.

Comment: @RevanProdigalKnight Thanks :) Included your suggestions also in the answer.

Comment: Awesome! thanks. What if I need to add another capital letter such as this example `AB01-123`?

Comment: @oramel You just need to change the RegEx like this `[A-Z]{2}\d{2}-\d{3}`